# Update a PRIMARY ID field with auto increment

Tags: mysql

MSQl question:
I have a web page the has a number of fields going against a msql database.

3 tables: 
1. ID = primary key, INT. Auto Increment
2. Name = text field, 
3. Address = text field

On that web page I'm showing all fields, but only fields 2,& 3 can update and not the PRIMARY KEY. basically, I see the issue that trying to overwrite a field that is auto generating is probably the problem. But I need the auto increment because on another web page I'm adding a record that the product web page gets the record and displays it online.

Question; Is there a way to (OVERWRITE) update a PRIMARY ID KEY field that is auto incremented?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily update a record with a primary auto_increment key just like any other field, but the values must remain unique.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, that does not help me in this instant. Perhaps I was not very clear. If I can update 2 out three fields and the main primary key if the one not updating when displaying on the web page but the others do. I managed to make sure the data and the field i unique. But when I add a new data text in that field of the PRIMARY ID it does not update. Very puzzling...